# Material Expansion Panel with NGFOR seems to lockup my js resources

Tags: angular, angular-material, material-design, angular-material2

I added the MatExpansionModule to the application module started doing some tests.

creating a singular `mat-expression-panel` renders, but if i wanted to create a bunch of panels dynamically with a ngFor, it will lock up my webpage.

I was trying to understand why this was happening and possibly rectify it.

I was testing against various designs and explicitly applying ngFor to this implementation will fail.

Tried the following:

1. ````html
   <div *ngFor="let item of sampleList"> {{item.name}}</div>```
   ````
2. ````html
   <mat-expansion-panel>
     <mat-expansion-panel-header>TEST</mat-expansion-panel-header>
     Test String
   </mat-expansion-panel>```
   ````
3. ````html
   <mat-expansion-panel *ngFor="let item of sampleList">
     <mat-expansion-panel-header>{{item.name}}</mat-expansion-panel-header>
     Test String
   </mat-expansion-panel>```
   ````

The last one (3) is where it fails.

In an attempt to exure it wasnt the nested data, I leveraged the content as just a simple string.

It seems that the issue itself is the ngFor with the a sample list which is:

```
const sampleList = [{name:"test"}, {name:"foo"}, {name:"bar"}];
```

Maybe there is an issue with Material components with ngFor? Maybe there is a solid alternative?  Im trying to make a means to show or hide data in this kind of fashion.  Are there some solid alternatives with Material Designs, or is this a flaw because because i cant use a forloop with Layout components?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have issues with change detection performance. Angular Material designed very good, so try to look for problem in your code. Can you create some stackblitz to reproduce issue?
About tunning performance:
 - Add trackBy function to ngFor (will prevent rerendering of whole list once list is changed)
 - Check, that you have ChangeDetectionStrategy.onPush set for this component
 - if you have a lot of items in list (really a lot) - try to use CDK virtual scrolling

Comment: Ill take a look at get back to you.  The item list is between 26 and 160. While each has 25 properties, i dont even render that.  Its weird that it would work with just a div, but doesnt work with the mat-expansion-panel.